# Masking areas in OpenGl

Tags: opengl-es, libgdx

I've got a libdgx game that I'm working on. I've got a progress bar and need to fill just the inside of it. If it was a square progress bar this would be easy - but my graphics man would like rounded ends. Example below.

[image: Progress bar]

To fill the progress bar I have a 1px wide texture that I stretch across the required width. Is there a way I can use a mask in OpenGL so that when I'm drawing the texture to fill the progress bar it only fills inside the blue line.

Thanks.

Comment: To do this, I think you'll need a custom shader (so your progress bar wouldn't be batched with other sprites). Otherwise, OpenGL can only mask rectangles (it's called scissoring). I can think of a few different ways to do what you want. Some involve multi-texturing, which would require creating your own Mesh instead of using SpriteBatch, or a carefully set up TextureAtlas and custom shader. But if the fill can be described with a function from top to bottom (or if it's just a solid color), you could do it in your shader and use a custom Sprite subclass.

Comment: Another option to consider is using a stencil buffer.

Comment: Oh yeah, there's that, but it will have aliased edges. Not a problem if you subsequently draw a border sprite over the whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Libgdx/Android ninepatch texture to render a texture with fixed-size corners and a "stretchy" middle.   See https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Ninepatches